# How to form a group based on nearest days of previous and next weeks?

Tags: python, pandas

I was asked to re build my previous question so I deleted it and created this one.

My input is a dataframe with two columns :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['Tuesday, November 7, 2023', 'Wednesday, November 8, 2023', 'Thursday, November 9, 2023', 'Friday, November 10, 2023', 'Monday, November 13, 2023', 'Friday, November 17, 2023', 'Sunday, November 19, 2023', 'Monday, November 20, 2023', 'Thursday, November 23, 2023', 'Friday, November 24, 2023'], 'WEEK': [45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47]})

print(df)
                          DATE  WEEK
0    Tuesday, November 7, 2023    45
1  Wednesday, November 8, 2023    45
2   Thursday, November 9, 2023    45
3    Friday, November 10, 2023    45
4    Monday, November 13, 2023    46
5    Friday, November 17, 2023    46
6    Sunday, November 19, 2023    46
7    Monday, November 20, 2023    47
8  Thursday, November 23, 2023    47
9    Friday, November 24, 2023    47
```

Logic : I need to form groups of custom weeks. For example, for the rows with week `46`, we need to look for the nearest day in weeks `45` and `47` and form the group. If a week has no previous (like week `45`) we flag it with a missing TAIL and if a week has no next week (like `47`) we say that he has a missing HEAD. So the pair group/missing will be unique at the final.

```
                          DATE  WEEK  GROUP MISSING
0    Tuesday, November 7, 2023    45      1    TAIL
1  Wednesday, November 8, 2023    45      1    TAIL
2   Thursday, November 9, 2023    45      1    TAIL
3    Friday, November 10, 2023    45      1    TAIL
4    Monday, November 13, 2023    46      1    TAIL
5    Friday, November 17, 2023    46      2    NONE
6    Sunday, November 19, 2023    46      2    NONE
7    Monday, November 20, 2023    47      2    NONE
8  Thursday, November 23, 2023    47      3    HEAD
9    Friday, November 24, 2023    47      3    HEAD
```

There is a detail, my real dataset have different years. It means that the groups must reset (start from 1) for each year.

I started making the groups with the code below but from the beginning I got shifted groups. I'm not able to fix it and also won't be able the create the MISSING column.

```
df['GROUP'] = ((df['WEEK'].diff() == 1).shift().cumsum() + 1).fillna(1)
```

Can you guys help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a weekly period ([`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)+[`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)) to build masks for [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.to_period('W')

m1 = ~s.isin(s.add(1))
m2 = ~s.isin(s.sub(1))

df['MISSING'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['TAIL', 'HEAD'], 'NONE')
```

*Note that you can choose how to [anchor your weekly periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets).*

Output:

```
                          DATE  WEEK MISSING
0    Tuesday, November 7, 2023    45    TAIL
1  Wednesday, November 8, 2023    45    TAIL
2   Thursday, November 9, 2023    45    TAIL
3    Friday, November 10, 2023    45    TAIL
4    Monday, November 13, 2023    46    NONE
5    Friday, November 17, 2023    46    NONE
6    Sunday, November 19, 2023    46    NONE
7    Monday, November 20, 2023    47    HEAD
8  Thursday, November 23, 2023    47    HEAD
9    Friday, November 24, 2023    47    HEAD
```

Intermediates:

```
                          DATE  WEEK MISSING                      s     m1     m2
0    Tuesday, November 7, 2023    45    TAIL  2023-11-06/2023-11-12   True  False
1  Wednesday, November 8, 2023    45    TAIL  2023-11-06/2023-11-12   True  False
2   Thursday, November 9, 2023    45    TAIL  2023-11-06/2023-11-12   True  False
3    Friday, November 10, 2023    45    TAIL  2023-11-06/2023-11-12   True  False
4    Monday, November 13, 2023    46    NONE  2023-11-13/2023-11-19  False  False
5    Friday, November 17, 2023    46    NONE  2023-11-13/2023-11-19  False  False
6    Sunday, November 19, 2023    46    NONE  2023-11-13/2023-11-19  False  False
7    Monday, November 20, 2023    47    HEAD  2023-11-20/2023-11-26  False   True
8  Thursday, November 23, 2023    47    HEAD  2023-11-20/2023-11-26  False   True
9    Friday, November 24, 2023    47    HEAD  2023-11-20/2023-11-26  False   True
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm impressed because I was expecting the answer to be many lines of code. Can you tell me please how to create the column `GROUP` ? There is also a detail, only two groups should have TAIL and HEAD missing. For example with a dataset having dates along 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024.. only the very first group of 2021 will have missing tail and only the last group of 2024 will have a missing head. All the reamining middles will have NONE missing.

Comment: For the first question `pd.factorize(df['MISSING'])` is an option, for the generalization to several years, can you open a new question?

Comment: Also, clarify the logic for the GROUP, how should it be if you have several weeks with NONE?

Comment: Ok i'm building a new question to make an example that reflects my real dataset, thank you so much for your time.